# How to execute some code before Hibernate Bootstrap in Wildfly in a web application?

Tags: hibernate, wildfly

In a web application that

- deployed as a single war file
- runs on the Wildfly 20
- uses Hibernate as its persistence layer(Wildfly builtin mosule)
- 

I have some code that must be executed before than Hibernate Bootstrap.
what is best practice for doing this task??

Comment: Could you desсribe in common what this code actually do and why do you want to run it before hibernate bootstrap.

Comment: @SternK the code is a sort of database validation and altering code that along the other things executes some SQL scripts that contains DDL and DML instructions. the source of this altering and validation is out of entity model(at legacy/metadata level of our application) and to avoid conflicts in database it is required to be executed before than Hibernate bootstrap, In fact before than EntityManagerFactory creation.